# Setting an image for an ImageCell in ListView on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a project on Xamarin Forms with a ListView. Inside of my ListView I have an ImageCell. When the project is being ran, it only shows the the ImageCell's text. I need it to show the text, the detail, and the image. I have coded what I thought looks correct but I can't figure out why it's not working. My images are in my resources folder and I labeled them correctly. The point of this project is to create an event calendar. The user will create an event, choose the date and time of the event, save it, and it should show up with a picture of the day of the week the event is on, the name of the event in the text portion, and the date and time of the event in the details portion. Can someone take a look at my code and see what I have done wrong?
Here is my `MainPage.XAML` :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MorganHall_CE04.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Code Example 4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell x:Name="imageCell" Text="" Detail="" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="addButton" Text="ADD EVENT" HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my `MainPage.XAML.CS` it's a lot...:

```
    {
        private List<TaskData> taskList = new List<TaskData>();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            addButton.Clicked += AddButton_Clicked;
            
            DataTemplate events = new DataTemplate(typeof(ImageCell));
            events.SetBinding(ImageCell.TextProperty, new Binding("Text"));
            events.SetBinding(ImageCell.DetailProperty, new Binding("Date" + "Time"));
            //SetValue to change color properties
            events.SetValue(ImageCell.TextColorProperty, Color.DarkBlue);
            events.SetValue(ImageCell.DetailColorProperty, Color.DarkMagenta);
            //SetImages ex: saveButton.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("save48.png");
            string image = SetImages();
            events.SetValue(ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, ImageSource.FromFile(image));
             

            listView.ItemTemplate = events;
            

            //Ask the listView to let us know anytime an item gets selected
            listView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "ModifiedMessage", (sender) =>
            {
                this.ReloadListData();
                Debug.WriteLine(sender);
            });

            //Reload saved list items when app is opened
            this.ReloadListData();
        }

        private string SetImages()
        {
            //set string variable to hold the image source
            string picture = "";
            string day = "";
            //Check if taskList is empty
            if (taskList != null)
            {
                //loop through task list
                for (int i = 0; i < taskList.Count; i++)
                {
                    DateTime date = taskList[i].Date;
                    day = date.ToString("dddd");
                }
                
                //set images to the day of the week using a switch statement
                switch (day)
                {
                    case "Sunday":
                        picture = "sunday.png";
                        break;
                    case "Monday":
                        picture = "monday.png";
                        break;
                    case "Tuesday":
                        picture = "tuesday.png";
                        break;
                    case "Wednesday":
                        picture = "wednesday.png";
                        break;
                    case "Thursday":
                        picture = "thursday.png";
                        break;
                    case "Friday":
                        picture = "friday.png";
                        break;
                    case "Saturday":
                        picture = "saturday.png";
                        break;
                }
            }

            return picture;
        }

        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Push taskEntry page with what was selected
            //Double check if what was selected is valid
            if (e.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new TaskEntryPage());
                MessagingCenter.Send<TaskData>((TaskData)e.SelectedItem, "EditItemMessage");
            }

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            //Leave base.OnApperearing
            base.OnAppearing();

            
        }

        private void ReloadListData()
        {
            //Tell taskList to clear
            taskList.Clear();

            //loop through all files that were generated and add to task list and set to data source for listView
            // * means "anything as long as it matches the last half of file name
            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(App.FolderPath, "*.CE04.txt");
            foreach (var filename in files)
            {
                //Read information from file
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
                {
                    var data = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
                    //Convert the date string to a DateTime object
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(data[1]);
                    //Convert the time string to a TimeSpan object
                    TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(data[2]);

                    //Add data to the taskList
                    taskList.Add(new TaskData
                    {
                        Filename = filename,
                        Text = data[0],
                        Date = dt,
                        Time = time

                    });
                }
            }
            listView.ItemsSource = taskList.OrderBy(d => d.Date).ToList();
        }

        private void AddButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new TaskEntryPage
            {
                BindingContext = new TaskData()
            });
        }
```

And here is my `TaskEntryPage.XAML.cs` where the information should be getting saved and it's only saving the text it looks like:

```
    {
        TaskData editTask;

        public TaskEntryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Set pictures for 

            saveButton.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("save48.png");
            deleteButton.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("delete48.png");

            saveButton.Clicked += OnSaveButton_Clicked;

            deleteButton.Clicked += DeleteButton_Clicked;

            //subscribe to message from MainPage
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<TaskData>(this, "EditItemMessage", (sender) =>
            {
                editTask = sender;
                taskEntry.Text = editTask.Text;
                datePicker.Date = editTask.Date;
                timePicker.Time = editTask.Time;
            });
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            //Leave base.OnAppearing
            base.OnAppearing();
        }

        async private void DeleteButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool answer = await DisplayAlert("DELETE EVENT", "Are you sure you want to delete this event? This cannot be undone.", "YES", "NO");
            if (answer)
            {
                if (editTask != null)
                {
                    //Check if file already exists
                    if (File.Exists(editTask.Filename))
                    {
                        //Delete file
                        File.Delete(editTask.Filename);
                    }
                }

                MessagingCenter.Send<string>("ModifiedMessage Called from Delete", "ModifiedMessage");

                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            } 
        }

        private void OnSaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = Path.Combine(App.FolderPath, $"{Path.GetRandomFileName()}.CE04.txt");
            string messageType = "New";
            messageType = "Edit";
            var binding = BindingContext as TaskData;
            binding.Date = datePicker.Date;
            binding.Time = timePicker.Time;
            //I can't figure out another way besides StreamWriter
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                //write data to file
                writer.WriteLine(taskEntry.Text);
                writer.WriteLine(datePicker.Date);
                writer.WriteLine(timePicker.Time);
            }

            MessagingCenter.Send<string>("ModifiedMessage Called from " + messageType, "ModifiedMessage");

            Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

and last not least, my `TaskData.cs` that holds the filename, date, and time:

```
    {
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    }
```

I know it's a lot but I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: There is a LOT wrong where.  First, why are you creating the template in both XAML and code?  Pick one  or the other (generally XAML is preferred).  2nd, `Binding("Date" + "Time")` won't do what you want.  Doing this in XAML and using a `FormatString` will be much simpler. 3rd, `SetImages()` isn't doing anything useful.  You could greatly simplify this by using an `IValueConverter` to convert the `Date` to a string to use as the image source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code just as Jason said.

I have achieved this function based on your code and it works properly. You can refer to the following code:

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ImageCellApp.converters"
             x:Class="ImageCellApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:DateToStringConverter x:Key="dateToStringConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="Code Example 4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>
        <ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ImageCell x:Name="imageCell" Text="{Binding Text}" ImageSource="{ Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource dateToStringConverter}}" >
                        <ImageCell.Detail>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                <Binding Path="Date" />
                                <Binding Path="Time" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </ImageCell.Detail>

                    </ImageCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button x:Name="addButton" Text="ADD EVENT" HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private List<TaskData> taskList = new List<TaskData>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ReloadListData();
    }

    private void ReloadListData()
    {
        //Tell taskList to clear
        taskList.Clear();

        taskList.Add(new TaskData { Filename = "fileName1", Text = "text1", Date = new DateTime(2021,7,19) , Time= new TimeSpan(1,20,30) });
        taskList.Add(new TaskData { Filename = "fileName2", Text = "text2", Date = new DateTime(2021, 7, 18), Time = new TimeSpan(2, 10, 30) });
        taskList.Add(new TaskData { Filename = "fileName3", Text = "text3", Date = new DateTime(2021, 7, 16), Time = new TimeSpan(1, 9, 30) });
        taskList.Add(new TaskData { Filename = "fileName4", Text = "text4", Date = new DateTime(2021, 7, 16), Time = new TimeSpan(1, 8, 30) });
        taskList.Add(new TaskData { Filename = "fileName5", Text = "text5", Date = new DateTime(2021, 7, 15), Time = new TimeSpan(1, 7, 30) });
        taskList.Add(new TaskData { Filename = "fileName6", Text = "text6", Date = new DateTime(2021, 7, 12), Time = new TimeSpan(1, 6, 30) });

        listView.ItemsSource = taskList;
    }
}
```

class `DateToStringConverter.cs`

```
public class DateToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;

        string picture = "";
        string day = "";
        day = date.ToString("dddd");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------------> day = " + day);

        //set images to the day of the week using a switch statement
        switch (day)
        {
            case "Sunday":
                picture = "sunday.png";
                break;
            case "Monday":
                picture = "monday.png";
                break;
            case "Tuesday":
                picture = "tuesday.png";
                break;
            case "Wednesday":
                picture = "wednesday.png";
                break;
            case "Thursday":
                picture = "thursday.png";
                break;
            case "Friday":
                picture = "friday.png";
                break;
            case "Saturday":
                picture = "saturday.png";
                break;
        }
        return picture;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Note:

1.You have mixed up `XAML` and code for your page, we usually perfer to use `XAML` to achieve our page;

2.If you want to bind several fields to one view, you can use  [MultiBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding) to achieve this, so you can use following code:

```
                        <ImageCell.Detail>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Date" />
                            <Binding Path="Time" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </ImageCell.Detail>
```

3.If you want to display image based on field  `public DateTime Date { get; set; }`, you can use [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to achieve this.

```
public class DateToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;

        string picture = "";
        string day = "";
        day = date.ToString("dddd");

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------------> day = " + day);

        //set images to the day of the week using a switch statement
        switch (day)
        {
            case "Sunday":
                picture = "sunday.png";
                break;
            case "Monday":
                picture = "monday.png";
                break;
            case "Tuesday":
                picture = "tuesday.png";
                break;
            case "Wednesday":
                picture = "wednesday.png";
                break;
            case "Thursday":
                picture = "thursday.png";
                break;
            case "Friday":
                picture = "friday.png";
                break;
            case "Saturday":
                picture = "saturday.png";
                break;
        }
        return picture;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Thank you! I didn't know about multiBinding and I am super grateful to you for breaking this down and recreating it for me. Seeing it definitely helps me learn it better.